# Transfering Whatsapp data to an iOS mobile

Tags: android, ios, data-transfer, whatsapp

I've been searching for the past few days for software that would allow me to transfer WhatsApp data from my Android phone to my iPhone. It seems this is a long-standing issue since iOS and Android use different systems to back up WhatsApp history (Google Drive and iCloud respectively) which have different types of encryption.

I tried using `Move to iOS` while I was setting up the iPhone, but it didn't work (the progress bar would not bulge). There seem to be a number of different apps out there that do this (`AnyTrans`, `iCarefone`, `MobileTrans`, ...)  but not only are they all paid for, but I also found reports of people claiming the apps don't work or that they are unsafe.

I don't know if there is any way I could make the transfer "manually", without the need for a third party app, but I haven't found any information that would suggest there is. So I was wondering if anyone could either recommend a paid software that would work and be worthwhile, or know of any free alternatives so I don't lose my history.

Comment: Related on Android.SE: [Transfer WhatsApp conversations to iOS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175462/44325)