# Looking for tools to transfer WhatsApp data from Android to iPhone

Tags: iphone-app, data-transfer, whatsapp, android-app

I've recently made the switch to an iPhone and used the 'Move to iOS' app to transfer all my data, including WhatsApp chats, from Android. However, it seems the WhatsApp transfer didn't go through. On my Android device, WhatsApp is stuck on the following screen:

[image]

> Almost done!
>
> Please finish registering on your new phone.

WhatsApp is working on my iPhone, but pressing the 'Next' button on the Android screen above does nothing. I'm considering a secure third-party app for the transfer.

*Can you recommend any apps for transferring WhatsApp data from Android to iPhone?*
The data is already backed up on Google Drive.

Comment: Dupe (but not answered yet): [Transfering Whatsapp data to an iOS mobile](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/85051/520)